# Batch matmul sparse matrices with a dense vector

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have a 3-dimensional tensor **(n x p x m)** which consists of m number of unique **(n x p)** sparse matrices I want to batch multiply to a single dense vector **(n,)**. Prior to using sparse matrices, I had copied the dense vector m times and created a new matrix **(n x m)** and performed an `einsum` to return a new matrix **(p x m)**. However, einsum does not work for sparse tensors.

**Question**

How can I take a 3D tensor that contains multiple unique 2D matrices and batch multiply it with a single dense vector?

**Simplified example of data**

```
import torch

matrix1 = torch.tensor([[0,1,2],[3,0,4]]).to_sparse()
matrix2 = torch.tensor([[4,9,0],[0,5,7]]).to_sparse()

matrices = torch.concat((torch.unsqueeze(matrix1,-1),torch.unsqueeze(matrix2,-1)),-1)
>tensor(indices=tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]),
   values=tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 9, 5, 7]),
   size=(2, 3, 2), nnz=8, layout=torch.sparse_coo)

vector = torch.tensor([1,2])
>tensor([1, 2])
```

**Problem**

I don't think PyTorch currently supports any matrix multiplication method for 3D tensors. I would ideally like to be able to batch multiply my dense vector to all my sparse matrices simultaneously but am unsure if this is possible. E.g:

```
torch.matmul(vector,matrices)
>RuntimeError: reshape is not implemented for sparse tensors
```

This may be related to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14489) except it's asking the reverse of the situation I have.

Comment: Take a look at  [pytorch-sparse](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse). It offers sparse-dense and sparse-sparse matrix multiplication. It natively supports batched sparse-dense multiplication, for batched sparse-sparse check this issue [here](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse/issues/357)